# How to I add a command to be available from the auto run box for DVD videos?

Tags: 12.04, dvd, default-programs

In `System Settings --> Details --> Removable Media` there are drop downs to let you select what to do when you insert various media types.

I've written some scripts called things like `ripmovie` and put them in `/usr/local/bin`

They work from the command line correctly.

I want them to be available as options in the drop down that appears when you insert a DVD movie.

I've tried selecting "Other Application" but they're not in the list and you can't add new ones.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I toiled and toiled, and I finally found out how to do this!

Create a file that looks like this.  Using your example script, name it `ripmovie.desktop` and place it in `/usr/local/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=RipMovie
Comment=Rip movies
Keywords=Video;Movie;Film;DVD;Disc;Rip
Exec=/usr/local/bin/ripmovie %f
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;GNOME;AudioVideo;Video;
MimeType=x-content/video-dvd;
StartupNotify=true
```

Not all of the pieces of this are necessary, but the ones that are include the `Name`, the `Exec`, the `Terminal` line, and most importantly, the **`MimeType`**!  That is the piece of magic that System Settings is looking for!

I found that I had to play with the end of the `Exec` line.  Check out [the spec of `.desktop` files](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html).  I wound up just hard-coding my optical drive (`/dev/sr0`) in there to pass to my script.  If I ever get multiple drives, I'll worry about it then.

Comment: OK, now THAT'S awesome. Every other thing I've seen is some hideous udev config, which is outside of where I want it (in the user account's scope, not system wide).

Comment: Is there a mime type for an audio cd?

Comment: @RoboJ1M Yes, it is `x-content/audio-cdda`.  FYI, my answer does not fully work in 14.04 for me.  I had to fiddle with `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` to get it working.

Comment: And I think the real, final answer may have something to do with `xdg-desktop-menu`.  I'll have to play with it some more.